# Internships for PhD students (e.g. in data science or programming)

Tags: phd, career-path, internship, code

I still have 2-2.5 years of my PhD program, but it want to try my skills in programing, especially in the taste of data science (needless to say, I do it overnight for some hobby projects and I like it a lot).

Moreover, as working in companies may seem as one of the options "what to do after getting PhD", I would be nice to test how does it work for me in practice, and to learn skills, network, etc.

Is there such a thing as internships (e.g. in data science or programming) for PhD students?

If so, where to search for them?

(If it changes anything, I'm doing PhD in EU; but US would be a nice target.)

Comment: Yes this happens all the time.  Often you can find nice research internships by talking to your advisor (who probably knows someone)

Comment: @BenBitdiddle (I am after PhD; and I had a very nice internship in Bay Area.) Well, if my advisor had known then I wouldn't have asked it here. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes.** Almost every PhD student in my (US computer science) department has at least one summer internship between admission and graduation.  In fact, most PhD students go through multiple internships.

Off the top of my head, I know CS PhD students who have interned at Google (Mountain View, Manhattan, and Shanghai), Facebook, IBM, AT&T, Yahoo, Motorola, Microsoft Research (Redmond, New England, and Bangalore), Disney, Zynga, Los Alamos, Sandia, Argonne, and Livermore.  Most of these places regularly advertise for interns on the web.

Comment: I heard it from my friends doing PhDs in US (and also googled some stuff for them). However, I hardly see anyone doing the same in Europe. But them I have no idea if the companies are not interested (e.g. extra cost, no established contacts), no such culture in Europe (not that unlikely) or they are discouraged/not allowed (I'm not even sure if at my institute I can, but they are pretty open, so I will try).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: At least in some European countries (and possibly only in some fields), that may be related to the circumstance that such internships are usually done at some point between starting one's studies and getting the Master's degree (or equivalent). Some majors even require such an internship of at least a few months as a mandatory precondition for graduating. Once you have that degree, you enter your work life, either in the industry, or in academia while being a doctoral candidate, i.e. you are kind of past the point where you do internships rather than getting a permanent job.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Actually, most of the internships in my list were held by PhD students who were well past the master's/qualifying exam hurdle.  Late PhD students are more likely to get _research_ internships, which can help immensely in getting a research job (either industry or academia) post-PhD.

Comment: @JeffE: Granted, I have seen doctoral candidates do proglonged business trips for "exchanges" or "stays at other organisations" to see another research-oriented workplace beside their regular one. Usually, these are also meant to strengthen ties and further collaboration with the organisation one stays at, e.g. to promote the research of one's regular department, to serve as a liaison in a mutual project, or to draft a project proposal together with the other organisation for an upcoming mutual project. I presume those are such *research internships* and different terminologies are used.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Nope. They're internships, hired through the company's internship programs. Research in many computing companies looks a lot like academic research in computer science departments, except that industry researchers aren't surrounded by graduate students, who are an enormous source of energy and ideas. So they use internships to attract graduate students over the summer, and those interns become research collaborators, just as they are in their home departments.

Answer (score 4):

(Perspective from Germany)

- I've been programming for an IT start up as undergrad student (got in contact when one of the founders gave a presentation in a series of business start-up talks) and later done data analysis a few hours a week as PhD student for another company. It is done, also in Europe.
- Big companies offer positions on their web pages, e.g. [Merck](http://www.merckgroup.com/en/careers/global_job_search/global_job_search.html?jobLanguage=en&collapse=true&keyNumber=&searchString=&jobField1=&jobField2=&jobField3=&job1Location1=&job2Location1=&job3Location1=&jobOrganisation1=&jobOrganisation2=&jobOrganisation3=&jobDate=&searchType=advanced&tab=0%2C1&jobHot=&jobType2=Internship&jobType3=Cooperative&jobType4=Summer+Job)
- However, if you receive funding for your PhD project (scholarship), that often forbids further work for hire.
- The PhD may technically be your "private fun", depending on the field/university/country. If that is the case (here), you often get a teaching assistant part-time job assigned to earn some money. The institues have a real problem of getting the teaching done (to the point that I heard rumours that some departments want to make "did so many hours of teaching" a prerequisite for getting the PhD). These job offers are often not offers the student can take or leave. Refusing to teach may create a lot of bad blood (with the prof, who anyways doesn't have enough people to cope with the teaching workload, and with the colleagues who get a slice more of this work). But it will usually go right to the limit which you need to obey in order not to loose the student status. So in fact, you cannot go for a paid industry job, neither. More importantly, the vacations are the only time when you can continuously work on your research.
- These rules, however, do not forbid to volounteer in e.g. in open source projects.
- You may consider [Google Summer of Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Summer_of_Code) and similar programs (e.g. [Season of KDE](http://teom.org/blog/kde/announcing-season-of-kde-2012/)).
  It may be easier to convince your funder/employer that participating in such a program has much more importance than just earning some money, and that your contract with them could go dormant for the months in question.
  *Disclaimer: I've been mentoring at GSoC before and hopefully will again. :-)*

Comment: It's true that you're typically forbidden from doing other work for hire while you're employed by a university. However, for internships people take a leave of absence from graduate work for the duration of the intership (and therefore aren't forbidden from other work as they're not students for that time period).  That's the case in most places in the US, at least, and I've been told it's the same in the UK, though I know nothing about the rest of Europe.

Comment: As Joe mentioned, I expect to take a leave for the internship period. My main point of getting internship is not to get extra money, but valuable experience (both technical and of working in a company, which I never did). (Anyway, no teaching assistant part-time job at my place.) When it comes to GSoC - you brought an interesting option. However, I doubt that I would help much for persuading (except maybe for max 1 months instead of vacations; especially as my field is theoretical physics). Plus, daily f2f contact with other programmers are crucial for me (I code on my own, anyway.).

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: I don't understand your sentence "I doubt that I would help much for persuading" (the "for persuading"). Can you explain this a bit more, please?

Comment: @cbeleites Sure. My point was that I doing open source programming projects still does not count as doing theoretical physics, so doing open source internship (in general, I'm very for open stuff, see http://offtopicarium.wikidot.com/v1:open-science-2-0) most like would not help enough, when it comes to convincing advisor or institute.

Comment: @JoeKington: Typically here, you have a working contract for teaching of 19.5 h/week (and teach much more). The vacations are then the only time when you actually can concentrate on your research. So you don't want to go working then also. The possibility not to do teaching at your institute is often only theoretical. The institutes have far too few employees to do the teaching, and it has to be done. If you refuse this, your institute will just be mad at you. I heard rumours some departments are considering to make teaching a prerequisite for the PhD degree...

Comment: The 19.5 h/week derive from the fact that if you work for hire more than 20 h/week, you become a normal half-time employee, cannot get a student ID and loose all the benefits that come with student ID. There are also things like health insurance offering very low student rates (though I'm not sure whether/how much that applies for PhD students for sure it apples for undergrads, and it applies also for PhD students with scholarship).

Comment: @cbeleites - It's essentially identical in the US (except for the 19.5 hour contract).  You just take a leave of absence for a semester when you do an internship.  You're not refusing a TA, you're just not enrolled for a semester.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: so you are looking for a theoretical physics internship in industry? I don't think the "open source" is the convincing part of programs like GSoC. The convincing part is that being accepted for a project puts you into a top 800 worldwide category of students. And successfully finishing your project means that you have proven a very high level proficiency not only in programming but also in the soft skills necessary for finishing a project, integrating in a team and so on. There's also a wage, but IMHO having "successful participation in GSoC" on your CV is worth much more.

Comment: @cbeleites (Better priv or chat, as comments here are not intended for a discussion) No; my main point is to get real experience in data science or programming. I believe that GSoC counts well on CV. But first, it's not easy to get it. Second, I want finally a project when I'm in office doing programming with others, who are in physical proximity (one of reason is also to see an alternative of almost always lonely work in TP, with feedback once a few months).

Comment: @cbeleites When it comes to teaching, my institute is research-only. But in European univs its mostly this is a mandatory requirement, not an extra job.

Comment: @cbeleites: "you become a normal half-time employee, cannot get a student ID and loose all the benefits" - that must be university-specific. I know various universities in Germany where you (at least in CS) are employed as a full-time employee *and* can optionally keep your student ID to get many of the benefits (such as a significant discount on public transportation).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: there are significant benefits of the student status that you loose for sure with a full time job, namely the student status for social insurance (much lower fees e.g. for health insurance). You may not have noticed that as those fees are automaticically subtracted before the wage is payed out. Further it is AFAIK up to the university to decide whether you have student status or not. The universities I know use employee status for full-time employees: you then have employee benefits. Your student status would then be more like the student status of a Gasthörer (guest student).

Comment: @cbeleites: True, I was rather thinking of benefits within the university (or organisations in direct contact with it, such as public transportation, which can save well up to 1000€ a semester). The universities I know leave it up to doctoral candidates whether or not they want to register as students (who are then regular students, not guest students) in addition to being employed, in which case at any opportunity where student and employee benefits may apply, one can freely choose to use either the former or the latter. I think there is quite some variation there across states and places.